# How to suppress the welcome note and sign-in form on freshly installed chromium(for android) browser startup

Tags: android, shell, google-chrome, chromium, adb

I have created a script for modifying the chromium browser's behavior when it starts. If the browser is freshly installed and if anyone opens it for the first time, the user will get a welcome note and sign-in form, which I want to suppress.

According to my findings, the solution is to replace the /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs/org.chromium.chrome_preferences.xml file with a version that is generated after skipping the welcome note and sign-in form. The script changes the folder's permission successfully, replaces the file, and again changes back the folder's permission.

But when I open the browser after reboot or without rebooting, that file is overwritten again and I still get the welcome note and sign-in form in both cases. But if I manually replace that file through the Android device monitor and reboots the device, it works.

The browser I am using is [Chromium v73.0.3674.0](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Android/623108/) for android.

And here is the script

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/org.chromium.chrome"
su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs"
su -c "rm -r /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs/*.*"
su -c "cp /mnt/internal_sd/MokiMDM/org.chromium.chrome_preferences.xml /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs/"
su -c "chmod 660 /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs/org.chromium.chrome_preferences.xml"
su -c "chown root:root /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs/org.chromium.chrome_preferences.xml"
su -c "chmod 771 /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs"
su -c "chown root:root /data/data/org.chromium.chrome/shared_prefs"
su -c "chmod 751 /data/data/org.chromium.chrome"
su -c "chown root:root /data/data/org.chromium.chrome"
```

Thanks!